# DbContext with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, dbcontext

I know this question is sort of a repeat of a lot of questions but I can't for the life of me figure if I'm being an idiot and missing something really obvious or what. I need smarter people than myself right now to show me the way (or tell me I'm not insane).

Basically I was given a coding challenge by for an interview (not trying to cheat here, bear with me). Now the code provided "works", as in it builds and runs, except it doesn't actually work. Here's just a snippet of one of the provided controllers (changing the names for more generic stuff).

```
public class ExampleController : BaseApiController
{
    private readonly SomeRepository _repository;

    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetAll()
    {
        var items = await _repository.Items.GetAllAsync();
        return Ok(items);
    }
```

And this is what the BaseApiController looks like:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class BaseApiController : ControllerBase
    { }
```

Now the issue is very obvious, the _repository is never initialized. Duh. So I add a constructor to initialize this, and add the DbContext (which SomeRepository depends on):

```
public class ExampleController : BaseApiController
{
    private readonly SomeRepository _repository;

    public class ExampleController(SomeDbContext context){
        _repository = new SomeRepository(context);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetAll()
    {
        var items = await _repository.Items.GetAllAsync();
        return Ok(items);
    }
```

This works, I test it through postman and am able to get data back. However. It breaks every single unit test that was provided in the challenge. Why? The provided tests intialize the ExampleController class with the base constructor. Here's an example:

```
public class ExampleControllerTests
{
    private readonly Mock<ISomeRepository> _repository;

    public ExampleControllerTests()
    {
        this._repository = new Mock<ISomeRepository>();
    }

[Fact]
    public async Task Get_OnSuccess_ReturnsListOfItems()
    {
        Item[] monsters = ItemFixture.GetItemsMock().ToArray();

        this._repository
            .Setup(x => x.Items.GetAllAsync())
            .ReturnsAsync(items);

        ExampleController sut = new ExampleController();

        ActionResult result = await sut.GetAll();
        OkObjectResult objectResults = (OkObjectResult) result;
        objectResults?.Value.Should().BeOfType<Item[]>();
    }
```

Obviously I shouldn't modify the tests they provided, so is there a way to get the DbContext in the ExampleController without making a constructor that takes it as a parameter? Or should I resign myself to fixing the tests (in which case, how? Trying to initialize a DbContext doesn't work because it requires the DbContextOptions).

Comment: You should have DbContext Injected to the Repository (which is already there) and repository injected to the Controller instead of dbContext. Then in tests you create mock of repository and create controller object by doing `ExampleController sut = new ExampleController(_repository);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like they have already registered all the dependencies required that are to be injected into the controllers, otherwise injecting `DbContext` would fail.

The test you provided is definitely incomplete and meant to be fixed. They are mocking an `ISomeRepository`, but not using it in any way. Not to mention `ExampleController sut = new ExampleController();` wouldn't event work because you added `DbContext` as a constructor argument.

I'm going to assume that `ISomeRepository` is being bound somewhere in the DI container (along with `DbContext`). That would make your `ExampleController` look like this:

```cs
public class ExampleController : BaseApiController
{
    private readonly ISomeRepository _repository;

    public class ExampleController(ISomeRepository repository){
        _repository = repository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetAll()
    {
        var items = await _repository.Items.GetAllAsync();
        return Ok(items);
    }
}
```

The test would then used the mocked interface to verify the `GetAll` method.

```cs
public class ExampleControllerTests
{
    private readonly Mock<ISomeRepository> _repository;

    public ExampleControllerTests()
    {
        this._repository = new Mock<ISomeRepository>();
    }

    public async Task Get_OnSuccess_ReturnsListOfItems()
    {
        Item[] monsters = ItemFixture.GetItemsMock().ToArray();

        this._repository
            .Setup(x => x.Items.GetAllAsync())
            .ReturnsAsync(items);

        ExampleController sut = new ExampleController(_repository.Object);

        ActionResult result = await sut.GetAll();
        OkObjectResult objectResults = (OkObjectResult) result;
        objectResults?.Value.Should().BeOfType<Item[]>();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looked promising. Chaning the parameter from the DbContext to ISomeRepository worked, but changing the tests didn't. I even tried casting it but that didn't work either.

Comment: Oh sorry, Moq. I'm used to NSubstitute. I've edited my answer to use the `.Object` property when instantiating the controller.

Comment: Oh wow, my lack of knowledge with Moq really showed there. Thanks, that clears everything up. I'm still not sure because the documentation said not to modify the existing tests but I'll work with this and maybe I'll get an answer from them about that.